Set the distance-in height-between the nodes of the same level in visNetwork?
Is it possible to set the distance between nodes of the same level(for example here the 4 last nodes of the 3rd level)? I want to be able to set the distance(height) between them. Probably that would work if we set the distance in height between all nodes in a network but in any case Im intersetd speicifally for the 3rd level. I don not care about being able to move them later manually.
library(visNetwork)
# Create nodes data frame
nodes <- data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  label = c("BLADDER", "TRODELVY", "EV", "NO ADC RECEIVED", "EV", "NO ADC RECEIVED", "TRODELVY "),
  color = c("gray", "red", "blue", "gray", "blue", "gray", "red"),
  shape = "box",
  level = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

# Create edges data frame
edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)

# Create the network visualization
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visNodes(shape = "square", size = 500, font = list(color = "white")) %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)%>%
  visHierarchicalLayout(levelSeparation = 200, direction = "LR")

